# Stackmob fetchExtended not working

Tags: fetch, stackmob

I have started to use Stackmob as a backend for a simple app I am building.

In stackmob I have set a relationship between two schema's and want to use '.fetchExpanded' to grab all of the data from stackmob, see this fiddle (will need to view the console to see the output):

http://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/65Rax/

```
.fetchExtended(1);
```

The same code works using the '.fetch' instead of '.fetchExpanded'.

Has anyone come across this before?

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a work around for this.

Instead of using '.fetchExtended(1);' I will just use '.fetch();' and when I am defining the model I will change the following:

```
var Bike = StackMob.Model.extend({
    schemaName: "bikes"
});
```

to:

```
var Bike = StackMob.Model.extend({
    schemaName: "bikes?_expand=1"
});
```

This seems to remove the need for '.fetchExtended(1);'

Hope this helps someone else.